# ThemeRoller doesn't work on device

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I've created a mobile app and styled it with CSS and ThemeRoller on Dreamweaver. It looks great on safari but when I use PhoneGap Build to test it on my Android device, the styling disappears.

I've tried embedding the CSS as well as the ThemeRoller style into my code without any luck.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link href="styleSheet/fgStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="themes/fg-designs-custom-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> 
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried pasting that code into my work but it messed up my styling